# Using ASP.NET handler to upload files

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am using Plupload for multiple file uploads. The files are sent to a ashx handler which saves them. However, I also have a Fileupload control for users who do not have flash or javascript enabled. I am wanting to use the Handler to also handle uploads from the fileuplaod control so all my logic is kept in one place. Does anyone know if it is possible to send the file from the fileupload control to a handler?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how the fileupload control works. But you can try to create a workaround and have your logic in one place i.e to create a class that handles the uploaded file. Now both your handler and fileupload control will use this class to do the necessary with your files.